# python: hex to bin with binascii.a2b_hex results in binascii.Error: Odd-length string

Tags: python, binary, hex, binascii

i am trying to convert a hex string to bin using `binascii.a2b_hex` but i get `binascii.Error: Odd-length string` only with some strings, not everytime.

for example this is the string throwing the error: `177B16283F6C72F52DB9F00DF2629EB6F925A67AEF85A93F5588C62DCDB0050`

if i try to do `binascii.a2b_hex('177B16283F6C72F52DB9F00DF2629EB6F925A67AEF85A93F5588C62DCDB0050')` i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
binascii.Error: Odd-length string
```

just in case: i get this string converting in hex a string of bytes using:

```
"{0:0>4X}".format(int('0000000101110111101100010110001010000011111101101100011100101111010100101101101110011111000000001101111100100110001010011110101101101111100100100101101001100111101011101111100001011010100100111111010101011000100011000110001011011100110110110000000001010000',2))
```

i am not having this problem with other strings of bits different from this one

Comment: try this `'177B16283F6C72F52DB9F00DF2629EB6F925A67AEF85A93F5588C62DCDB0050'.strip().decode('hex')`

Comment: @EvilReboot i don't know if i have to cast some way but i get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 1):

string length is 63 instead of 64, because of missing leading zeroes. To fix this

```
binascii.a2b_hex('177B16283F6C72F52DB9F00DF2629EB6F925A67AEF85A93F5588C62DCDB0050'.zfill(64))
```